# NodeJS: extend Class and __construct method

Tags: php, node.js, class, methods, construct

Im migrating my system from PHP to NodeJS, and I have the following doubt:

In PHP, I have the class

```php
class Users extends Groups {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //do something
    }
}
```

But, how to do the same in Javascript/NodeJS (ExpressJS)?
I think is this to extends, but how I define the __construct method? What is the name of the method that will be called in the start of Class instance like in PHP?

```js
var utils = require('utils');
var Groups = require('./groups.js');
var Users = function(){
    //where is the __construct??
};
util.inherits(Users, Groups);
```

Comment: User **s**, Group **s** for a class name - smell of bad design.

Comment: I used the example just to illustrate my question, I haven't a function with these names - smell of excessive criticism.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude or anything, sorry for that - I was just stating that sometimes people misuse classes and shape them just like huge libraries of methods, not like proper models - with all chance not your case, I was just referring to the wider picture.

Comment: Ok, sorry too! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not `parent` construct specifically, so it is up to you to somehow call the parent constructor.

`inherits` adds a `super_` property to it's first argument

```
Users.super_ = Groups;
```

so you can call the parent constructor like this:

```
Users.super_.call(this); // Can pass arguments to function as more params.

// OR
Users.super_.apply(this, arguments); // Pass all arguments through.
```

or you can also reference the parent constructor directly:

```
Groups.call(this); // Can pass arguments to function as more params.

// OR
Groups.apply(this, arguments); // Pass all arguments through.
```